# Валидация формы на уникальное Имя

Tags: c#, асинхронность, asp.net-core-mvc

Хочу провалидировать с помощью своего собственного аттрибута форму.

Вот код:

```
public sealed class UniqueUserNameAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string userName = value.ToString();

        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            var user = await Managment.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
            return user;
        });

        task.Wait();
        var taskUser = task.Result;

        var validResult = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var resUser = taskUser.Result;
            if (resUser != null)
            {
                ErrorMessage = $"Name {userName} is already used";
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        });

        validResult.Wait();

        var isValid = validResult.Result;

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

но по каким-то причинам у меня вылетает исключение типа

```
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.))
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(int millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
csharpcourse.Areas.UniqueUserNameAttribute+<>c__DisplayClass0_0+<<IsValid>b__0>d.MoveNext() in UniqueUserNameAttribute.cs, line 16
```

Место в котором вылетает исключение:

```
validResult.Wait()
```

Использую в моделе так:

```
[UniqueUserName]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Для чего вы создаете таски и тут же вызываете `Wait`? Полная бессмыслица. Для начала уберите таски - станет намного легче отлаживать код.

Comment: Managment.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName); - в этой строке метод только асинхронный, потому что класс Managment - статический класс с таким содержимым: public static class Managment
    {
        public static UserManager<AppUser> UserManager;
        public static SignInManager<AppUser> SignInManager;
    }

Comment: Не пишите код в комментариях. Перенесите его в сам вопрос (нажмите ссылку _править_).